# Rails 3: How to accept natural key of child model on parent model form

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following code:

```
# app/models/part.rb
class Part < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :lots
  # attributes: id, number
end

#app/models/lot.rb
class Lot < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :part
  # attributes: id, number, part_id, quantity
end

# app/views/lots/_form.html.erb
...
<p>
  <%= f.label :number %><br />
  <%= f.text_field :number %>
</p>
<p>
  <% f.fields_for :part do |p| %>
    <%= p.label :number, 'Part' %><br />
    <%= p.text_field :number %>
  <% end %>
</p>
<p>
  <%= f.label :quantity %><br />
  <%= f.text_field :quantity %>
</p>
...
```

The form is supposed to edit or create lots. The form is to accept the part number of an existing part and save the part_id to the lot. The fields_for group isn't rendering for me. I'm sure this is easy. What is going on here is that the part number is a natural key but Rails uses surrogate keys. I could have used a select list but I need to accept keyboard input. I'll need to wire up ajax for the form eventually. What are your thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing an equals sign

`<%= f.fields_for :part do |p| %>`

In Rails 3, helpers usually return values, rather than printing them out directly.  Because of this, use <%= instead of <%

Comment: When the form is posted should I be doing a find of the part based on the part number and assigning that to the lot model and then the save? Or is there something I decorate the models with to do this implicitly? The <%= tag worked to the the field to appear but I'm getting a ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch error when I post the form.

Comment: Can you post a separate question and include your controller logic, as well as any relevant routes in config/routes.rb?

Comment: It is scaffolding code right now. I feel that reposting this question is going to hurt Jeff's feelings with how stackoverflow is supposed to work. My original paragraph of question should give a hint of what I'm trying to do here. I provided the code above to demonstrate what I'm working with and I'm trying to understand the overall concept of wiring up a nested field.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't mean to be difficult. Thanks for the syntax correction above. I solved my problem by adding a virtual attribute to my model in addition to your syntax fix above.